# how do I prevent vim from auto-wrapping at column 80

Tags: vim

As I'm writing code, when the cursor reaches column 80, vim automatically wraps the text by inserting a newline character. How do I prevent vim from doing so? Is there any setting that am missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just found that `set tw=0` works. It doesn't wrap lines by inserting a new line character at a predefined limit.

Added that `set` to vimrc to make it permanent.

Comment: When tw is 0 another option that is responsible for adding new lines is wm. Set wm to 0 to prevent adding new lines at reaching right window border.

Comment: this seems to be the default!  If you get text wrapping based on window size without lines actually being changed then you want the answer below

Answer (score 17):

The auto-wrapping is defined by `set wrap` and this option depends on the width of your window/screen, but it does not insert a newline character into the file.

The column **80** is defined by `set tw=80` this will change the text by adding new linebreaks for long lines.

To check details, you can:

```
:h 'wrap'
:h 'tw'
```

To disable auto-wrapping, you could:

```
:set nowrap
```

To disable long line auto broken, you can:

```
:set tw=0
```

0 is default.